# How to create a custom password field for Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

I need to login users registered in the table *Igrejas* that have the fields **responsavel_cpf** and **responsavel_senha**, but Laravel in the function *validateCredentials* expects the name `'password'`.

```php
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
}
```

I tried to login using *attempt* without success:

```php
$userdata = array(
    'responsavel_cpf'      => Input::get('email'),
    'responsavel_senha'    => Input::get('password')
);

if (Auth::guard('igrejas')->attempt($userdata)) {
    return Redirect::to('dashboard_paroquia');
} else {
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

What do I do to replace the default fields **email** and **password** with **responsavel_cpf** and **responsavel_senha**?

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: have you changes config > auth.php file 'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customusers',
        ],

Comment: @AmitKumar, I'm using 5.8.x version

Comment: @JadavPalak I try this, but he going for the same function that needed $plain = $credentials['password']

Answer (score 2):

You can override the password column in your user model like so:

```php
// User.php
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->custom_pw_field;
}
```

However, if you actually want to pass an array that does not explicitly contain `password` to `Auth::guard('xxx')->attempt($credentials)`  (for which there is no reason!), you'll probably have to override and add the `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` manually which seems a lot of work.

So I would suggest to just use the following:

```php
Auth::guard('xxx')->attempt([
    'email' => $request->post('email'),
    'password' => $request->post('password')
]);
```

The `password` key should then validate against the `custom_pw_field` that you defined.

#### Explanation

By looking at the source of `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` and checking the function `public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)`, you can see what it does:

- Find the first record in the auth table that matches all the conditions in the `$credentials` array except for `password` (so just `email` in the example above). So you could add for instance another key like `is_webmaster` like `$authGuard->attempt(['email' => $request->post('email'), 'is_webmaster' => 1])` which would then retrieve the first user record that has these properties.
- After this record is retrieved, the hash from its password column is then checked against your input.

Comment: The problem of his solution is that *email* not is replaced for *responsavel_cpf*.

Comment: if you read it fully you can see that you can freely replace `email` with any other column in your table, since it basically gets added to the query that gives you the -to be authenticated- record.